# How to find an object by a field value in Rest Assured?

Tags: java, groovy, rest-assured, gpath

I need to get to `code` of an array element that has `field` == `firstName`:

```json
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "field": "firstName",
            "code": "NotBlank"
        },
        {
            "field": "lastName",
            "code": "NotBlank"
        }
    ]
}
```

With JsonPath, the way to do it is `$.errors[?(@.field == firstName)].code`. How do I do the same in Rest Assured with its GPath syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't tried it but from the top of my head this ought to work:

```
errors.find { it.field == 'firstName' }.code
```

Answer (score 0):

`errors.find{e -> e.field == 'firstName'}.code`